# Force Logoff from - BASIC "Active Directory" Authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, basic-authentication

how can i force the user to be logged off the IIS Active Directory Authentication?

clearing the session does not seem to do it, and it's not a complete log off unless i close ALL my browser windows..

is it even possible to do via code?

Thank you!

or can i set a time out on the authentication? it seems like right now i can login in once, close the application and come back to it hours later, and not have to put it my credentials again...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not possible by the way you want it to be. Have a look at this article http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2004/05/01/activate-windows-impersonation-selectively.aspx

Comment: do you know if it's possible to set a timeout feature on the basic authentication instead?

Answer (score 0):

Do you use `ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider`? You can try with

```
FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage();
```